# iphone app icon size?

Tags: iphone, applications

Can someone tell me what size icons I should be including in an iPhone app.  Can I assume also that I should include two resolutions?  Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is a list of icon's resolution needed for iPhone, iPad and both of them.

- 29x29 iphone/ipad
- 40x40 iphone/ipad
- 50x50 ipad
- 57x57 iphone
- 58x58 iphone/ipad
- 72x72 ipad
- 76x76 ipad
- 80x80 iphone/ipad
- 87x87 iphone
- 100x100 ipad
- 114x114 iphone
- 120x120 iphone
- 144x144 ipad
- 152x152 ipad
- 180x180 iphone

To generate all of them, I recommend you an app called [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12) that accept a 1024x1024 and generate the ones you defined.

Comment: Thank you so much @jherran I am really only looking for the size and res that would be used as the icon used to start the app...... Thanks for the info on "Prepo" I will go and get it.